# Streaming from microphone input

Tags: javascript, axios, stream, mediarecorder-api

I'm recording from the user's microphone, and I want to save the output to the backend.
To gain time, I want to start saving the file before the user's recording ends.
So I take the user's recording blob by blob and I want to send it to the backend blob by blob (with rest and axios if possible).

Can someone explain to me how I can create a stream from an array of blob, start sending it, and continue to add blobs to the stream until the recording ends ?